# How do we know that we only need three second derivatives to represent all the second derivatives of a thermodynamic system?

Tags: thermodynamics

In the topic of Maxwell relations of thermodynamics, my books says

> Of all such derivatives, only three can be independent, and any given derivative can be expressed in terms of an arbitrarily chosen set of three basic derivatives. This set is
> conventionally chosen as ${c_p}$ , α, and ${κ_t}$. ...
> All first derivatives ( involving both extensive and intensive parameters)
> can be written in terms of second derivatives of the Gibbs potential, of which
> we have now seen that ${c_p}$ , α, and ${κ_t}$ constitute a complete independent set
> ( at constant mole numbers).

I was wondering if there is any methods (without calculation of derivative) ,finding that we only need three  second derivatives to represent all the second derivatives of a thermodynamic system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context that your thermodynamical system has 3 independent variables this is true. Because any other derivative along some direction in parameter space can be expressed as a linear combination of these. But in general, e.g. if you have like 200 particle species with all different chemical potential, I'm not sure if this statement is correct. (Or imagine other "thermodynamical forces")

EDIT: Adressing the comment: Suppose $f(x,y)$ depends on two independent variables $x$,$y$. Now you have a third one, $z(x,y)$ which can locally be inverted (This can be done if assumptions of the thm. of implicit inverse is satisfied). Then the derivative w.r.t. $z$ looks like:

$\frac{\partial f(z(x,y),x,y)}{\partial z}= \frac{\partial f(z(x,y),x,y)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x(z,y)}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial f(z(x,y),x,y)}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y(z,x)}{\partial z}$

per Assumption, these things are all well defined.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to ask: why can any other derivative along some direction in parameter space  be expressed as a linear combination of these

Comment: What if second derivative? Would it be the same?

Comment: And why we need exactly three second derivatives to express other derivative? Is there any math  behind it? Anyway, thank you for your answer!!

Comment: @Raffaella Define whatever is here as a new function, say $g$ and $h$ and repeat procedure.

Comment: @Raffaella The math behind this is regarding the space of parameters as a manifold, the thermodynamical potential as a scalar field and the derivatives (locally) are just the canonical basis vectors of your tangent space. Every other derivative can be obtained (clearly, because it is a basis of the vector space) as linear combinations of these (in this case 3) basis vectors.